# Secure cloud-based solution to let customers fill and e-sign a PDF

Tags: web-apps, pdf, hosted, signature

I have a client who is looking for the ability to design fillable pdf contracts. They want to ensure privacy and security of their customers data input into these pdf files. I was looking at [Docusign](https://www.docusign.com/) or [Echo/Esign by Adobe](https://www.echosign.adobe.com/en/home.html). They would transact less that 100 documents a year. Would be very convenient but not necessary to be able to fill out and esign on mobile as well.

Any experience, or pros and cons you can share.... any other products that have a secure cloud environment in which to do this esigning?

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to have a look at e-SignLive by Silanis at www.silanis.com. In addition to boasting the highest customer satisfaction in the market (check out software review site, [G2 Crowd](https://www.g2crowd.com/compare/docusign-vs-adobe-document-cloud-esign-services-vs-e-signlive-by-silanis)), e-SignLive is the only cloud e-signature service to have gone through a detailed security audit (called “SOC 2” if you’re interested) that highlights the extensiveness of the processes and the security of the cloud-based e-signature platform. There are a number of articles on e-signature security at the bottom of this page – definitely worth a look: https://trust.silanis.com. I recommend reading the one titled, “Protecting Customer Data in the Cloud”, which will answer your client’s questions around privacy and security.

Best of luck with your e-signature project!

Comment: Please post screenshots showing a customer filling fields in a PDF, and explain the whole signature process (from the point of view of the customer). Also, please clearly state the price. Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you if you have already found a solution. If not, I would like to recommend the following software tool to you, [eSign Genie](https://www.esigngenie.com/).

The eSign Genie tool features the ability to create reusable templates, send PDF documents to be signed through the eSign Genie tool, create fields on the document to enter values (names, numbers, etc.), generate an online form and easily send the link to the recipient.

eSign Genie also has a versatile API so that instead of trying to install a whole new system, you can simply integrate the eSign Genie API into your present application or website.

The price is very reasonable, and their friendly customer service is always prepared to help with your needs. I would recommend this tool for its ease of use and efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Do you have any affiliation with eSign Genie?

Comment: Please post screenshots showing a customer filling fields in a PDF, and explain the whole signature process (from the point of view of the customer). Also, please clearly state the price. Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Hello, you can check this video for using the software:

Comment: Hello, you can check this video for using this software:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GSEcvUGrPM&feature=youtu.be

Follow this link for their pricing:
https://www.esigngenie.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

I just had to search for such a tool myself. There are tens of tools now, but most have funny pricing (as in: as expensive as a whole server).

It takes a time to sift through all of that. Here are the tools that I found recommendable so far (based on price and functionality combined):

- [SignRequest](https://signrequest.com), my favourite due to the pricing and integrated [PDF form filling feature](https://help.signrequest.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002895645)
- [DocHub](https://dochub.com/)
- [DigiSigner](https://www.digisigner.com/)
- [eSignly](https://acc.esignly.com/)
- [PingSign](https://www.pingsign.com/)
- [Countasign](https://www.countasign.com/)
- [Secured Signing](https://www.securedsigning.com/)